# Tkinter continuous check for text

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I have a simple interface set up using Tkinter.I have a drop down box, which is irrelevant. I also have two entry widget boxes. What I want to happen is for the second one to initialize as DISABLED, but AS SOON AS any text is entered in the first box I want the second one to become active. For some reason, my second box does not activate when text is entered into the first box. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()
    root.title("ShotBot")
    root["padx"] = 40
    root["pady"] = 20
    root.geometry('500x200-400+200')
    root.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)

    textFrame = Frame(root)


    #Create and place Option List

    var=StringVar()
    choices = ['a','b','c']    
    var.set(choices[0])
    entryWidget = OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
    entryWidget["width"] = 30
    entryWidget.pack(side="top")


    #Create and Place Text Field

    entryWidget2= Entry(textFrame)
    entryWidget2["width"] = 30
    entryWidget2.pack(side="top")



    #Create and Place Text Field

    entryWidget3 = Entry(textFrame)
    entryWidget3["width"] = 30
    entryWidget3.pack(side="top")


    textFrame.pack()

    button = Button(root, text="Submit")
    button.pack()

    if entryWidget2.get().strip()=="":
        entryWidget3["state"]=DISABLED
    else:
        entryWidget3["state"]=NORMAL



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is assign a value to the `textvariable` option of the first entry widget, place a trace on the variable, and then enable or disable the other widget depending on the current value of the variable. Something like this:

```
#Create and Place Text Field

def on_variable_trace(*args):
    if entryVariable2.get() == "":
        entryWidget3.configure(state="disable")
    else:
        entryWidget3.configure(state="normal")

entryVariable2 = StringVar()
entryWidget2= Entry(textFrame, textvariable=entryVariable2)
entryWidget2["width"] = 30
entryWidget2.pack(side="top")
entryVariable2.trace("w", on_variable_trace)
```

Comment: I am curious about your answer. I'm not at all familiar with this `trace()` method. Could you link me to an API?

Comment: @acattle: The trace method on variables lets you set up a callback whenever a Tkinter variable is accessed (read, written or deleted). Read up on variable traces here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm. Tkinter has several features that are somewhat unique for a GUI toolkit; this is one of them. It's a very powerful construct.

Comment: @BryanOakley That worked beautifully. I wasn't aware of the text variable option. Thank you so much!